# Excel VBA: Automation error- Remote procedure call failed

Tags: regex, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am extracting certain data from a website. I have to do this task for at least million rows from a table. I am using excel VBA to connect with MySQL.

- Using MySQL to connect with excel VBA, I am getting first name, last name of an author from a table.
- For the first name, last name of an author, I am appending Linkedin to the search query and  I am searching in Google.
- From the search results, I am opening the first search result page in the HTML format and extracting some information.
- I put back some of the extracted information into MySQL tables.

Everything works fine as per the above steps. However, if I try to do it for more than 10 rows I get the following error.

> Automation error the remote procedure call failed and did not execute

I realize it is something to do with the opening/closing of IE. In my program, I have the following code.

To create a new IE application, I have defined as below.

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Set RegEx = New RegExp
Dim iedoc As Object
ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & FirstName & "+" & LastName &  
"+linkedin&meta="
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
MyStr = ie.Document.body.innerText
Set RegMatch = RegEx.Execute(MyStr)
```

After extracting the data for one author, I have the below piece of code at the end.

```
ie.Quit
Set RegEx = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
Dim strBatchName As String
strBatchName = "F:\command.bat"
Shell strBatchName
```

The command.bat has the following code.

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM iexplore.exe /T
```

It works perfectly fine if I have lesser than 10 rows in my table. However, for more number of rows I do get the above mentioned error.

Comment: From many previous posts, I figured out the problem may be any one of the following.                                                        * I checked from services.msc if the remote procedure call service is enabled. It is enabled.                                          * Also, I unchecked the "Enable protected mode" in the internet options security tab.

Comment: I am running windows 7 and 32 bit version of excel 2010 (Professional plus 2010). Is it related to some version of excel or improper binding in references? I have the reference set to Microsoft excel 14.0 objects library. I am not able to trace out the exact error. I am going in a loop again and again and it seems the error happens no matter what changes I do. I believe that there must be some resolution, but not able to figure out.

Comment: Why do you close IE after only one search?

Comment: @rdnobrega is that what is causing this error?

Comment: @MattCremeens : Yeah, most probably! I'd be easier (and faster) to keep the instance of IE but just use the same tab to navigate to each URL!

Comment: I did that and it seemed to help. Can anyone tell me why this error happened, though?

Comment: @rdnobrega this seems to fix the issue in this post, but I now occasionally get this error: microsoft excel is waiting for another application to complete an ole action. Any clue?

Comment: Are you sending these requests to the same website or different ones? I have gotten my IP address blocked for a suspected DDoS attack unless I build in a timer delay (or get my IP address added to the 'safe list')

Answer (score 3):

I would be more tempted to use the same instance of ie to get all authors data, looping through them like in the example below.  Also, what is your batch file doing with the data?  I've never found the need for batch files to help with vba executions.  Are you using them to write text files?  You can accomplish that with vba also.

```
Dim ie As Object, lastRowAuthors as long, i as long, strBatchName As String

lastRowAuthors = sheets("Authors").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Set ie = New InternetExplorer


for i = 1 to lastRowAuthors

    ie.Navigate "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & sheets("Authors").range("A" & i).value  & "+" & sheets("Authors").range("B" & i).value &  
    "+linkedin&meta="
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop


    Set RegEx = New RegExp

    MyStr = ie.Document.body.innerText
    Set RegMatch = RegEx.Execute(MyStr)

'*****************************************************************
'   Use your REGEX commands to extract data
'*****************************************************************
    strBatchName = "F:\command.bat"
    Shell strBatchName
next i

ie.Quit
Set RegEx = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing

end sub
```

Comment: Having just one instance of internet explorer did seem to solve the issue. I still don't understand why it solves it, but I'll count this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: As for your question, this is actually someone else's question I offered the bounty on. I wasn't actually running any batch files, I was just getting the error mentioned and wanted to know why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the solution I found for this is :

1. Use the version as suggested by John Muggins where you only quit and set Internet to nothing after the end of your loop
2. Add a pause between each ne search such as a second to make sure it can go through each records and search for them with no problems. In order to do this I suggest to add either `Application.Wait Now + 1` before the `ie.Navigate` line, either add an extra sub to do this operation

   ```
   Sub WaitFor(PauseInSeconds As Long)
     Dim SngSec As Long
     SngSec = Timer + PauseInSeconds
     Do While Timer < SngSec
     DoEvents
   Loop
   ```

   End Sub
3. Extra : If you have as you said "millions of row" you should definitely add an error handler which retrieves the eventual rows where the code crashed so that you don't have to make sure that it runs properly all the way. Do this with an `On Error Resume Next`. Then you can either check those rows manually either store their index in an array and go through each of them a second time.